# Cookie gets removed on browser close after calling Response.Cookies.Set

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am creating a cookie that expires after 3 days with the following:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("website_cookie");

cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I am using a chrome plugin called "EditThisCookie" to view the cookie and everything looks good.  At this point if I close the browser and reopen it,the cookie is still there.

The problem occurs when I want to  update a value in the cookie by doing something like:

```
Response.Cookies.Set(cookie)
```

Now when I view the cookie with the plugin, the expiration has been removed and it is set to expire during session, so when I close and reopen now, the cookie is gone.

Is there a way to update the cookie value(s) while keeping the expiration date and not setting it to expire on session?

Comment: You may remove and add it again

Comment: @Khazratbek - What would be the point of the update if I had to keep removing and adding it. Also,  wouldn't that cause the expiration date to keep moving forward?

Comment: But actually you have to use: *Response.Cookies["website_cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);*

Comment: Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Khazratbek - When setting expires, are you saying I can't set it on cookie variable?  or is does that line refer to when I add/remove it?

Comment: No, it doesn't refers to adding/removing - it is updating expiration date of your cookie

Comment: Open a link what I shared, and you may see the whole life cycle of cookies using c#

Comment: You need to change the value of `cookie` like `cookie.Value="newval"` that is different from the value of same cookie that exists just before the line of code that calls `Set` method, else it will have no effect.

Comment: @Sunil - The cookie is updating fine.  I have a multi value cookie and when I set the value of one of the values, it gets updated.  The problem is, when I call Response.Cookies.Set(cooke), it turns into a session only cookie.

Comment: You need to set its expires property also. Did you try setting its expiration property?

Comment: @Sunil - When I originally create the cookie, I set it.  I just found out that if I set the expiration before calling set, it stays, but what this does is cause the expiration date to keep moving forward 3 days.  For example, if I create the cookie on January 19, it initially should expire January 22, but if I update cookie on January 20, the new expiration is now January 23 which is not what I want, I want it to still expire January 22.  How can I get around this?

Comment: @Sunil - I tried that, it always returns 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.  Maybe I have to store the expiration in the cookie

Comment: You need to somehow get the expiration date of original cookie from Request.Cookie. But since you cannot get this expires property, so you will need to set it in the cookie value  and then parse this cookie value to get expires date.

Comment: `cookie1.Value = string.Format("{0}|{1}", "cookie value", "10/10/2017 1:00 PM")`